# How to correctly use the plural form of genus (genera)?

Tags: grammatical-number

For example:

> Cercis, canna and catalpa are all genera of flowers

– just doesn't sound right.

How should it be used correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: That seems right to me.

Comment: Yup, seems perfectly fine to me as well.

Comment: Yes, according to Longman, Dictionary of Contemporary English,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, according to Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English the plural of genus is (Latin)
genera, used especially when talking of animals or plants.

Comment: It's true! You just have to realize that things are never going to "sound right" if you're speaking botanical Latin.

Comment: Oh, ok. Then, would it be more appropriate to say "flower genera" instead of "genera of flowers"?